# Problema al recibir datos por GET en android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
private static PostResponseAsyncTask task;
task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(Registrados_HassMovil.this);
task.execute(url_mostrarinformacion+"?fecha="+registro.getText().toString()+"&huerto="+huerto.getText().toString());
```

> Aqui el problema no acepta palabras con espacio es decir
>   *huerto=**hola mundo***

```
@Override
    public void processFinish(String s) {
        String Estado;
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        Informacion.putExtra("id", (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")));
                    }
                    startActivity(Informacion);
                    finish();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Cuando es una palabra simple es decir el la parte de la url donde mando por get el parametro *huerto* sea **hola** hasta alli todo bien pero si mando **hola mundo** no me retorna nada por el espacio que hay. Alguna solucion?

Comment: Ese es un error que puede pasar en cualquier lenguaje. Si vas a mandar información en la "query string" tienes que escapar los caracteres especiales y los espacios. Por ejemplo, para los espacios hay que sustituirlos por el signo +. Pero sería conveniente que no lo hagas a mano y busques la forma de hacerlo con las librerías que estés utilizando.

Comment: Definitivamente debes de codificar la variable mediante  URLEncoder.encode() de acuerdo a la respuesta de @cnbandicoot

Answer (score 2):

Las URL no aceptan espacios, así como otro carácteres. En las URL se convierten en carácteres especiales. Podrías utilizar la clase `URLEncoder`

```
 try{
    String q = "hola mundo";
    String url = "http://prueba.com/consulta?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```